# Unable to download torrents on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, networking, bittorrent, transmission

I am unable to download using torrent on OS X Yosemite, but the weird part is that  able to do that on a windows machine on the same network.

Router reports that the port is open, but the torrent application says the port is closed.

I have tried both uTorrent(not installed in the machine currently) and Transmission version 2.84 (14306)). OS X Yosemite version 10.10.3

Comment: Can you check whether the port is blocked locally or not?
Edit: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18635?locale=en_US

Comment: @stigvis I have checked the security settings Firewall is ON, and for Transmission all the incoming transmissions are allowed.

Comment: The fact that you are able to use a torrentclient on another machine on the same network suggests that you either have the torrentclient blocked in the firewall on your Mac, or the router in your network. I would recommend double checking the settings in the router and in your firewall. Do you have anything else between the router and your Mac?

Comment: @stigvis I have check the port forwarding in router, router reports that the port is open (along with the application name and ip address) and in Mac firewall is ON and torrent client is not blocked (I have even tried switching OFF the firewall)